# How to delete object stored in mulitple lists

Tags: python

There are seven class instances declared. To three of them the same argument value is assigned (stored in `self.myList` attribute).
All seven instances are stored in `inst_listA`. A half of them is stored in `list_B`.

Now I iterate `list_B` to see if there are any instances I want to delete (in this example I want to delete three instances that store the same value). As soon as I locate a such instance I apply `del` expecting deleted instance to be removed from both lists: `inst_listA` and `inst_listB`. But that apparently doesn't happen.
**Question**: how to delete variables (object instances) from the list so they are removed permanently from any occurrence every else in a code.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, myList):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.myList = myList
    def getList(self):
        return self.myList


inst1=MyClass([1,2,3, None])
inst2=MyClass([3,4,5, None])

inst3=MyClass([6,7,8, None])
inst3_1=MyClass([6,7,8, None])
inst3_2=MyClass([6,7,8, None])

inst4=MyClass([9,10,11, None])
inst5=MyClass([12,13,14, None])

inst_listA=[]
inst_listA.append(inst1)
inst_listA.append(inst2)
inst_listA.append(inst3)
inst_listA.append(inst3_1)
inst_listA.append(inst3_2)
inst_listA.append(inst4)
inst_listA.append(inst5)

inst_listB=[]
inst_listB.append(inst2)
inst_listB.append(inst3)
inst_listB.append(inst3_1)
inst_listB.append(inst3_2)
inst_listB.append(inst4)

print inst_listA    
print inst_listB
for inst in inst_listB:
    if inst.getList()==[6,7,8, None]:
        inst_listB.remove(inst)
        del inst
        print 'instance deleted'

print inst_listB
print inst_listA
```

Comment: `inst_listB.remove(inst)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That removes one copy from one list. He wants to remove all copies from all lists. (Plus, removing values from a list while you're iterating it is illegal.)

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to build up lists that laboriously; just do `inst_listB = [inst2, inst3, inst3_1, inst3_2, inst4]`.

Comment: @abarnert, there are only two lists

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: And? There are 6 copies of one of the values (well, 2 references apiece to 3 copies). Removing one of them is not removing 6.

Comment: Within a `for` loop I believe the `inst` contains a copy of the instance. For deleting stuff from list, you generally recreate the list object with `filter` or `[ j for j in js if js not in [6,7,8] ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `del` statement doesn't actually delete an object, it just deletes a name. So, when you do this:

```
for inst in inst_listB:
    if inst.getList()==[6,7,8, None]:
        del inst
        print 'instance deleted'
```

… you're just deleting the local name `inst`. Any other names for the object, like `inst_listB[1]`, are still there. There's no way to wipe out all names for a value at the same time, because the value has no idea of all the names people have given it.

Think of how this would work in real life: I get my phone book and look up Sputnix, then I tear out the page you're on. There's no way that could affect every other phone book in the city. Even if I could delete the value—you—by, say, tracking you down at a nightclub and shooting you (assuming Kyle Reese isn't there to stop me)—that still wouldn't take you out of all of those phone books, it would just mean nobody could use those phone books to call you anymore.*

At any rate, it looks like what you want to do is remove all copies of `[6, 7, 8, None]` from both lists. The easiest way to do that is to do it directly:

```
inst_listA = [inst for inst in inst_listA if inst.getList() != [6, 7, 8, None]]
inst_listB = [inst for inst in inst_listB if inst.getList() != [6, 7, 8, None]]
```

---

<sub>* The literal equivalent of this in Python would be to put weak references into the lists. That makes sure there's only one real reference, and when you kill that, the weak references are still there, but have nothing to refer to—just like the phone book entry for a dead person. But you don't want to learn about weakrefs yet.</sub>

Comment: I hoped I wouldn't have to clean up other variables that point to the same data.

Comment: @Sputnix: In most realistic programs, there are better solutions to this, but for generic `inst_listA`-type toy examples, there's really no good way to suggest anything.

Comment: how will inst ever be equal to  `[6, 7, 8, None]` does `__main__.MyClass object at == [6, 7, 8, None]` on your computer?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Sorry, that should be `MyClass([6, 7, 8, None])`. I'll fix it.

Comment: so `inst ==[6, 7, 8, None]` is True yes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: How did you get that from my last comment? Anyway, I think checking `inst.myList` is a better way to do this than constructing an instance just to compare against, so I edited my code that way instead.

Comment: @abarnert, I knew when you were on about dups that you were thinking on comparing lists and not instances.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, thanks for making me notice that, definitely! But that isn't really relevant to the problem. Notice how little of a change I had to make to the listcomps to change the way dups are defined.

Comment: @abarnert, sometimes an inch is a mile ;)

Comment: I looked at `weakref` docs. And I would have to say `weakref` does look suspiciously attractive. Are there any downsides of using it?

Comment: @Sputnix: The real issue is that what it's _meant_ to be used for is creating caches, back-links, etc. that don't unnecessarily keep objects alive, so using it to instead implement manual lifetime management and get hooks on deletion is at least a little fishy. That being said, if you want to go down that road, check out [`WeakKeyDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary) and friends in the stdlib; notice that the docs link to the source, which shows how to do what you want.

Comment: @Sputnix: Also, as the warning says on `WeakKeyDict`, in non-toy code, it can get tricky to make sure nothing you do while iterating over one of these types causes the dict/list/etc. to mutate indirectly, which is illegal.